# Coming multiple and statemnts syntax issue

Tags: javascript

```
if ((mouseX >816) && (mouseX <1000)) && ((mouseY>546) && (mouseY<730)){
    fill(85,107,47);
    ellipse(908,638,92,92);
};
```

I'm having an issue trying to get this to work. I think I have the correct syntax but apparently not. What would be the correct way to write this out?

Comment: You've got too many parentheses. The `if` statement takes **one** expression inside `( )`. There can be more `( )` inside, but only one outer group.

Comment: ^^ and you don't need any nested `()` at all if all of your conditions are `&&`, just the ones required by `if`: `if (mouseX > 816 && mouseX < 1000 && mouseY > 546 && mouseY < 730) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many parenthesis !!

```
if ((mouseX >816) && (mouseX <1000) && (mouseY>546) && (mouseY<730)){
    fill(85,107,47);
    ellipse(908,638,92,92);
};
```

And btw, because there is only "AND" conditions, you can totally avoid parenthesis

```
if (mouseX >816 && mouseX <1000 && mouseY>546 && mouseY<730){
    fill(85,107,47);
    ellipse(908,638,92,92);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help the OP! But here on SO, we don't post *answers* for basic syntax errors and other typo-level errors. Instead, we vote to close them as "typo/non-reproducable/not useful to others in the future" and (if appropriately) post a *comment* explaining the typo instead.